# Finding a instances of a string inside a string

Tags: python, string, bioinformatics

I'm working through the bioinformatics problems on rosalind.org and I've come across a problem where the python script I've written works on a smaller dataset but when applied to a larger one, I get the `IndexError: list index out of range` message.

Basically I have both a smaller motif and a larger DNA sequence and I have to find instances of the motif in the DNA sequence. When I put the sample dataset in the question into my script, it works fine and I get the right answer. However, using significantly larger motifs and sequences yields the previously mentioned error.

This is my code:

```
motif = "<motif around 9 characters>"
cMotif = list(motif)
motifLength = len(cMotif)

dna = "<DNA sequence around 900 characters>"
dnArray = list(dna)

locations = ""

position = 0

for nt in dnArray:
        if (nt == cMotif[0]):
                for x in range(0, (motifLength)):
                        if ((x + position) > len(dnArray)):
                                break

                        if (dnArray[position + x] == cMotif[x]):
                                if (x >= (motifLength - 1)):
                                        locations += (str(position + 1) + "      ")
                                       break 
                        else:
                                break
        position += 1

print(locations)
```

The `IndexError: list index out of range` error occurs at line 18, `if (dnArray[position + x] == cMotif[x]):` hence I added the

```
if ((x + position) > len(dnArray)):
                                    break
```

but this doesn't make a difference.

Cheers

Comment: Hint: The last element in `dnArray` is `dnArray[len(dnArray) - 1]`. Re-check your guard condition.

Comment: The guard condition cMotif occours too late

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's lists are zero-based, so when `(x + position) == len(dnArray)` trying to access `dnArray[x + position]` will be one past the last index. You should change your test to `if (x + position) >= len(dnArray):` to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use python's regex instead for easiness.

```
import re
motif = "abc"
dna = "helloabcheyabckjlkjsabckjetc"

for i in re.finditer(motif,dna):
    print(i.start(), i.end())
```

It gives you the start,end index in the string for every occrence of `motif` in `dna`

Comment: It's worth noting that `re` will not find overlapping sequences. eg. `re.finditer("abab", "ababab")` will only match at position 0-4 and not 2-6.

Comment: ok. Didnt consider that originally, but adding positive lookahead may solve that

Answer (score 0):

Here is your program that throws an error:

```
motif = "abcd"
cMotif = list(motif)
motifLength = len(cMotif)

dna = "I am a dna which has abcd in it.a"
dnArray = list(dna)

locations = ""

position = 0

for nt in dnArray:
        if (nt == cMotif[0]):
                for x in range(0, (motifLength)):
                        if ((x + position) > len(dnArray)):
                                break

                        if (dnArray[position + x] == cMotif[x]):
                                if (x >= (motifLength - 1)):
                                    locations += (str(position + 1) + "      ")
                                    break 
                        else:
                                break
        position += 1

print(locations)
```

I changed `if ((x + position) > len(dnArray)):` to `if ((x + position) >= len(dnArray)):` and the error goes away because your program is never going to the `break` statement because you are not checking for the `"="` condition. Remember, in programming languages things start from 0.

Put this line above your condition `if ((x + position) > len(dnArray)):` and you will know the reason:

```
print("My position is: " + str(x+position) + " and the length is: " + str(len(dnArray)))
```

The last line of this print statement will indicate that `My position is: 33 and the length is: 33`

See here that you have reached the end of the line and it does not match your existing criteria to go in the break statement.